# gazebo, use of urdf vs. sdf

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

does anyone know, whether there is some documentation explaning the role of urdf vs sdf in fuerte? spawning urdf models in gazebo one gets a lot of warnings about the deprecated use of urdf!? gazebo says it would prefer sdf.

Also, what is the correct way to tell the new gazebo to load a model plugin using an urdf file? Is there an example somewhere? The current docs and howtos are a little short in this respect.

Thanks in advance

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33548/gazebo,-use-of-urdf-vs.-sdf/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-05-08**:
I've been wondering the same things.  I cannot get sdf paths to work correctly so don't typically use them. gazebo_worlds/objects has some examples of urdfs that use plug-ins.  Also, in other posts I had thought they said the warnings posted when loading urdf files would be fixed in a new release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Andy! After some more research and experiments I would answer these two questions as follows:

1. URDF seems to be still the format of choice for specifying robots models in ROS. The Warnings mentioned are possibly due to the early version of fuerte and will possibly vanish in the future
2. The method to load model plugins did obviously not change in fuerte. still use the urdf within a  tag.

Best

Georg

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3